# Odometry in erratic simulation

Tags: ros, navigation, simulation, odometry, erratic-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi people. I am actually running a simulation of erratic robot on gazebo when this particular question strike me. The launch file I used is "erratic_navigation_apps demo_2dnav_slam.launch ".

For my project's purpose, I am trying to change the sources of odometry. When I do a rostopic check and tf_viewframe , I realised that the gazebo is producing the odometry information( the transformation from odom to base_footprint).

But when I run through all the launch files, I can't find which section is responsible for generating the transformation. Or is it that, in a Gazebo simulation, the odometry of the robot will be generated automatically?

In short, may I know which node in "erratic_navigation_apps demo_2dnav_slam.launch" is producing the odometry information? Thank you for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50246/odometry-in-erratic-simulation/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It apears that the transofrm from /base_footprint to /odom is being published by the diffdrive gazebo plugin from the erratic_gazebo_plugins package.  You can find the code in the function publish_odometry() in this [file](http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/erratic_robot/trunk/erratic_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin.cpp).

The plugin is being launched as part of the robot description .xacro [file](http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/erratic_robot/trunk/erratic_description/urdf/erratic_base.xacro).

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-12-12**:
Thanks JonW!

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-12-13**:
No problem.